# Can we purposely mispell a word?

Tags: grammar

> Whoever built the house, **he builded** better than he knew; or else
>   Orion in the zenith flashed down his Damocles' sword to him some
>   starry night, and said, "Build there." For how, otherwise, could it
>   have entered the builder's mind, that, upon the clearing being made,
>   such a purple prospect would be his?—nothing less than Greylock, with
>   all his hills about him, like Charlemagne among his peers.

This is from Herman Melville's The Piazza and I encountered the above sentence. The past form of build is built, and not builded. Is there any reason why he used "builded"?

Comment: Are you asking about this specific case only or intentionally misspelling words in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, "builded" is an archaic or nonstandard version of "built". There are some good usage examples here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/builded

In this case it seems like a "poetic" or "literary" nonstandard usage. I think the phrase "builded better" has a kind of rhythm to it - there's alliteration (both words start with "b") and each word has two syllables.